# How to integrate MSTest And MSBuild results in Cruisecontrol (v2.8.4)

Tags: msbuild, mstest, cruisecontrol

How do you integrate MSTest and MSBuild results into specifically CruiseControl 2.8.4. I've read documentation online, but it seems to be outdated and not in line with how the later versions of cruisecontrol work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you talking about cruise control or cruisecontrol.net could you arrange the tags or your post?

Comment: I venture to doubt that. Current version of CruiseControl.NET is 1.5.7256.1

Comment: Sorry mate, you are correct, 2.8.4 is just normal cruisecontrol